# Tem alguma maneira de pegar o que o usuário esta ouvindo?

Tags: react, react-native, native

Gostaria de saber se tem algum modo ou até mesmo uma lib para que eu possa pegar as informações do player de áudio do celular, como duração da música, nome, álbum etc. com o react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aplicações de iOS e Android não conseguem acessar dados nem memória uma das outras, e a leitura dos mecanismos de output dos dispositivos é muito limitada. Você não vai conseguir fazer uma aplicação que consiga pegar o áudio do dispositivo, nem de outras aplicações. Essas limitações são por design, para evitar invasão de privacidade.

A única forma de se obter o que o usuário está ouvindo é recorrer a API's das aplicações que reproduzem som. Com o Spotify, por exemplo, as API's do iOS e do Android não vão lhe ajudar, mas a API Web [lhe permite ver a última música que o usuário ouviu](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#play-history-object). Você pode dar sorte de ser a música que o usuário está ouvindo na hora da sua consulta, mas não há garantias.

Cada aplicação diferente será um mundo diferente a explorar. Boa sorte.